# My Scala Spark code doesn't work, although pyspark it works fine

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running Linear regression in Pyspark with multiple parameters and it works fine, But if run the same code with same configuration in scala it gives me below error on fitting the model.

Please ask question and I will put all the details, I am stuck here since last one month.

19/12/06 23:59:35 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 6 on bvpr-bdaws09.vq.internal.vodafone.com: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits.  1.5 GB of 1.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.

one thing more in scala if I just directly fit the linear regression model without multiple parameters then it also works.

```
val spark = (SparkSession.builder
         .appName("MLib_scala")
         .master("local")
         .config("spark.driver.memory", "3g") 
         .config("spark.executor.memory", "20g") 
         .config("spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors","5")
         .config("spark.executor.cores", "3")
         .config("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead","2g")
         .enableHiveSupport()
         .getOrCreate())

val df1 = spark.sql("select * from Table_4kCols_10k_rows") //some 3GB hive table
val list_cols =df1.columns
val featureCols = list_cols.filter(_!= "dormant_flag")
val df2=df1.withColumnRenamed("dormant_flag","label")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureCols).setOutputCol("features")
val df = assembler.transform(df2)
val seed = 5043


val Array(train, test) = df.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val lr = new LogisticRegression().setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("features")
val fittedLR = lr.fit(train) // This works fine
val stages = Array(lr)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(stages)
val params = new ParamGridBuilder().addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, Array(0.0, 0.5, 1.0)).addGrid(lr.regParam, Array(0.1, 2.0)).build()
val evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator().setMetricName("areaUnderROC").setRawPredictionCol("prediction").setLabelCol("label")
val tvs = new TrainValidationSplit().setTrainRatio(0.75).setEstimatorParamMaps(params).setEstimator(pipeline).setEvaluator(evaluator)
val tvsFitted = tvs.fit(train) //This gives an error //pyspark works fine
```

Comment: As mentioned in the error message you should change the "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" configuration value (by allowing more memory).

Comment: Yes true, But that is not the case.
because the data set is like 3G and I already allocated 10g memory with 5 executors.
Also the question is without grid it works fine, as you can see in the comments code above. Also with the same memory configuration if I run it through pyspark it also works fine.
Please help me , I can send you more detail, if you wanto to

Comment: are you using the exact same input dataset and same number of partitions in both cases? What about your spark.executor.cores in both scenarios ?

Comment: Yes the cores are same,data set is same, and the same code runs in pyspark.
I have update the code in the question so that you can read the complete code.

Comment: Thank you @INAM for this update. Can you also add a few more precisions : 
(1) How many partitions are used in your DAG ? 
(2) Which storage format is used for your Hive Table ? (orc, parquet, csv, ...)
(3) Just to be sure, does Spark UI show the exact same configurations for both Scala and Python codes ? ie: sometimes spark-submit / jupyter override your settings.

Comment: Thank you for the help so far, I am using CDSW and spark 2.4 , the table format is text(org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat) 
The spark UI doesnot show the exact same configuration , also in YARN i can see the memory utilization for pyspark is 123 GB ,with which my container was created, While for skala this memeory utilization is either very low like 4GB , or some times 250 GB (I mean configuration is 5*20+10 = 110 GB)

Also by running this command df.rdd.partitions.size , in both it gives me 2 partititions and I just check the table size and it is only 175 mb